# ASP .Net MVC 2 custom Helper Grid not posting Model to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've created a custom helper that renders a grid and receives the strongly typed view's model as a parameter.

Basically my view looks like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateValues", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { %> 

    <%= Html.MyGrid(Model)%>

    <input type="submit" value="Update Values" />

<%} %>
```

But when I click on the submit button, all the values on the model are null.

This is what the controller looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string UpdateValues(AssignmentResultsVm assignmentResults)
    {
        //..... do something
    }
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the items are arranged in your grid so that the default model binder can map the data map to your view model class.

This is done by index the name property of the data your are binding like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />

    <input type="text" name="[1].Title" value="Code Complete" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Author" value="Steve McConnell" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can have this done for you by the EditorTemplates feature of asp.net mvc which is exemplified in [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so very much! Also the collection is a property of a complex object itself so it actually has to be "Books[0].Title" and so forth.